# How to force a ItemsControl fo validate row changes?

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm, observablecollection, idataerrorinfo

I have a `Model` called `PhoneModel` and a `ViewModel` called `PersonViewModel` that both of them impelements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `IDataErrorInfo`. In `PersonViewModel`, i have a `ObservableCollection<PhoneModel> Phones` property that are shown in a `ItemsControl` in my view. So, I create some `Command`s to add and remove `PhoneModel` items from `Phones`. But in add, edit, and delete of them, the `Validation` not fired. How can I force to `ItemsControl` to validates its content? Is there any way?

```
public class PhoneModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo {
    // has some validation roles and IDataErrorInfo is implemented full
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

public class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo { 
    public ObservableCollection<PhoneModel> Phones { get; set /* implements INotifyPropertyChanged */ ; }
}
```

and in view:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Phones}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox 
                    Text="{Binding Number,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                        Mode=TwoWay,
                        ValidatesOnExceptions=True, 
                        NotifyOnValidationError=True,
                        ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                    />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Can you help me please? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1**

I try `@Michael G`s answer, but still not works. My code is here:

1) I add a collection-changed event handler:

```
Phones.CollectionChanged += PhonesChanged;
```

2) and in it I try:

```
void PhonesChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Action != NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        return;
    var model = e.OldItems[0] as PhoneModel;
    if(model != null) {
        model.Validate();
        OnPropertyChanged(() => Phones);
    }
}
```

3) also I try to listen each phone item's property-changed:

```
foreach(var phone in Phones)
    phone.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(phone_PropertyChanged);
```

and:

```
void phone_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    var phone = sender as PhoneModel;
    if(phone == null)
        return;
    phone.Validate();
    OnPropertyChanged(() => Phones);
}
```

Comment: @MichaelG How can I do this? I cant understand (I cant understand English so good)

Comment: What validation is not running? The `PhoneModel` validation, or the `PersonViewModel`? Your `PhoneModel` validation should be running, while your `PhoneViewModel` validation won't. It might help to see your validation code as well.

Comment: Actually, when I set break points, it seems both of validations run; `PersonViewModel` and `PhoneModel`'s `string IDataErrorInfo.this[string columnName]` getter called when a property of them changed; But the `PersonViewModel`'s error shown in view, but the `PhoneModel`'s error take not any effect in view

Comment: And about accept rating, I got it. Ok. Thanks

Comment: @Rachel thank you very very much. I understand -just now- my `IDataErrorInfo` impelementation has a bug (and cant read `ErrorMessage`s from resource files). So the code has no errors! but there isnt any error message to show. And this happend because of your suggestion: `"It might help to see your validation code as well"`. Thank you again so much

Comment: And for now, @Michael 's answer the one answer that its not helping me. How can I accept it? Please post your suggestion as an answer to accept it.

Comment: @king.net You can actually post your own answer and accept it. It helps other users who encounter the same problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Listen to the [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) event on the Phones ObservableCollection.

```
Phones.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Phones_CollectionChanged);

void Phones_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     //ValidatePhones();
     // OnPropertyChanged("Phones"); // Let IDataErrorInfo know
}
```

Also, you can listen to each "PhoneModel"'s PropertyChanged event in the PersonViewModel to invoke validation for when a property on the PhoneModel object changes.

Comment: Thanks. I try your suggestion, but not works. I update the Q and put my try code. Can you look at it please?

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion. But actuallt it not help me. The error was `IDataErrorInfo` implementation. I +1 your answer but cant accept it. Thanks again. Regards